# Why does Perl allow mutual "use" relationships between modules?

Tags: perl

Let's say there are two modules that mutually use each other:

```
package a;
use b;
sub p {}

1;

package b;
use a;
1;
```

I think that it is systematically wrong to write code like the above, because the two modules will endlessly copy each other's code to themselves, but I can successfully run the following code, which makes me very surprised.  Could any of you explain all of this to me?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use a;
a->p();
```

Comment: 'Use'ing a module does not copy anything, unless you set up an `@EXPORT` or otherwise specifically copy something into another symbol table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> because the two modules will endlessly copy each other's code to themselves

No, they won't, as you demonstrated with the code that surprised you by working.  Perl keeps a record in `%INC` of which modules have been loaded with `use` or `require` and will not attempt to reload them if they get `use`d or `require`d again.

Answer (score 9):

There are (at least) three different ways of loading something: `use`, `require` and `do`.

`use` is basically a pimped `require` and perldoc [states](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) for `require`: *require demands that a library file be included if it hasn't already been included.* So no problem there.

`do` is a different story. It executes the file and is more or less like `eval` or C's `#include`. Mutual inclusion via `do` should be fatal.

Comment: `do` is evil and is best avoided.

Comment: When you goal is to execute an arbitrary file (hey, this is Perl) rather than including it as a package then `do` seems to be the way to go. Maybe it does not really fit in this context; I just remember it that way because _Beginning Perl_ lists `do` in the chapter about modules.

Comment: If your goal is to execute an arbitrary file, then you may wish to reconsider your design.

Comment: @daotoad: That's what my remark in parentheses was for. In general you are right.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I remember "use" perl directive performs checking whether module is already loaded. It's done by calling require() function.  So, there is no endless copy.